# How to pass data as query in Flutter Web while opening a widget in new Tab?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am building a web app in Flutter web. I want to open a new tab and I want to show Google Map in that tab. For that, I need to have Latitude and Longitude passed to that new tab. So how can I pass the latitude and longitude as query params in URL? Or is there any other way by which I can open a widget in a new tab and pass data to it?

Comment: Hello, Kindly show us the work that you have done so far. Also, mention the flutter version that you use.

Comment: You should use Navigator 2.0 for this use case: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade.
There are also some packages on https://pub.dev which could be helpful.